# Android service isn't starting

Tags: android, service, gps

I am developing an android app to get location. I wanna lunch the gps tracker in a service to get location every 5 seconds in background and toast the location on the screen. My app works well when I run the service in MainActivity. However, it kills my app when I wanna lunch the GPS tracker in background (in service).

Here is my MainActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button startButton;
GPSTracker gps;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

    //gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

    intent = new Intent(this, GPSTracker.class);
    //startService(intent);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //intent = new Intent(this, GPSTracker.class);
            startService(intent);

            /*if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Your Location is -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
                                + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }*/
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My GPSTracker service:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

//private final Context context;

public static final String TAG = "com.timesavii.intent";

boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location;

double latitude;
double longitude;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker() {}

//public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    //this.context = context;
    //getLocation();
//}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand method called");

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
                getLocation();
                if (canGetLocation()) {
                    double latitude = getLatitude();
                    double longitude = getLongitude();

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your Location is -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
                                    + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    showSettingsAlert();
                }
                long futureTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
                while(System.currentTimeMillis() < futureTime)
                    synchronized (this){
                        try {
                            wait(futureTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                        }catch(Exception e){}
                    }
            }
        }
    };

    Thread myThread = new Thread(runnable);
    myThread.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (location != null) {

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }

            }

            if(isGPSEnabled) {
                if(location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if(locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if(location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}


public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if(locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

public double getLatitude() {
    if(location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if(location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

The manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.timesavvi.locator">

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".GPSTracker"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
    01-25 15:52:07.170 2408-2408/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
    01-25 15:52:07.200 2408-2408/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    01-25 15:52:07.200 2408-2408/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
    01-25 15:52:07.220 2408-2408/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
    01-25 15:52:07.250 1301-1329/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=2417 uid=10003 gids=    {50003, 9997, 1028, 1015, 1023, 2001, 1035} abi=x86_64
    01-25 15:52:07.280 2417-2426/? D/DefContainer: Copying 3@base.apk@classes.dex --instruction-set=x86_64 --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m
    01-25 15:52:07.590 2434-2434/? W/dex2oat: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
    01-25 15:52:10.280 2434-2434/? I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 2.830s (threads: 1)
    01-25 15:52:10.280 1301-1329/? W/PackageManager: Code path for pkg : 
    01-25 15:52:10.280 1301-1329/? W/PackageManager: Resource path for pkg : com.locator changing from /data/app/com.locator-1 to /data/app/com.locator-3
    01-25 15:52:10.370 1301-1329/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.locator appid=10061 user=0: pkg removed
    01-25 15:52:10.390 1301-1334/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
    01-25 15:52:10.420 1301-1334/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
    01-25 15:52:10.440 1301-1334/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
    01-25 15:52:10.470 1540-1540/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5243(504KB) AllocSpace objects, 52(4MB) LOS objects, 31% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 0 total 100ms
    01-25 15:52:10.480 1301-1313/? W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10ms
    01-25 15:52:10.480 1301-1313/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9218(782KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(96KB) LOS objects, 6% free, 11MB/11MB, paused 10ms total 90ms
    01-25 15:52:10.480 1301-1329/? I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 40ms for cause Explicit
    01-25 15:52:10.520 1781-1781/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.gms
    01-25 15:52:10.540 1781-2436/? D/PackageBroadcastService: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.locator
    01-25 15:52:10.590 1600-1600/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
    01-25 15:52:10.590 1600-1600/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
    01-25 15:52:10.630 1781-2442/? D/PackageBroadcastService: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.locator
    01-25 15:52:10.700 1781-1781/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.gass from APK com.google.android.gms
    01-25 15:52:10.730 1781-1781/? D/AsyncTaskServiceImpl: Submit a task: k
    01-25 15:52:10.770 1301-1301/? D/BackupManagerService: Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.locator flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
    01-25 15:52:10.770 1301-1301/? W/BackupManagerService: Removing schedule queue dupe of com.locator
    01-25 15:52:10.820 1301-1318/? W/VoiceInteractionManagerService: no available voice recognition services found for user 0
    01-25 15:52:10.840 1781-1781/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.gass from APK com.google.android.gms
    01-25 15:52:10.890 1781-1781/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.vision from APK com.google.android.gms
    01-25 15:52:10.900 1781-2447/? D/k: Processing package: com.locator
    01-25 15:52:10.940 1781-2444/? I/PeopleContactsSync: triggerPendingContactsCleanup: no accounts
    01-25 15:52:10.980 1781-2447/? D/GassUtils: Found app info for package com.locator:1. Hash: 607a580ba8b114d1bb81233a4f43c87943595c82273a2c0687ee3129357d1d28
    01-25 15:52:10.980 1781-2447/? D/k: Found info for package com.locator in db.
    01-25 15:52:11.050 1301-1644/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=2449 uid=10041 gids={50041, 9997, 1028, 1015} abi=x86_64
    01-25 15:52:11.080 957-957/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 707(30KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 90% free, 110KB/1134KB, paused 0 total 40ms
    01-25 15:52:11.100 957-957/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5(160B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 90% free, 110KB/1134KB, paused 0 total 20ms
    01-25 15:52:11.120 957-957/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4(112B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 90% free, 110KB/1134KB, paused 0 total 0
    01-25 15:52:11.140 1781-2444/? I/PeopleDatabaseHelper: cleanUpNonGplusAccounts done.
    01-25 15:52:11.160 1781-2444/? I/PeopleContactsSync: triggerPendingContactsCleanup: no accounts
    01-25 15:52:11.420 1781-1781/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.gass from APK com.google.android.gms
    01-25 15:52:11.430 1781-1781/? D/AsyncTaskServiceImpl: Submit a task: k
    01-25 15:52:11.440 1781-2465/? D/PackageBroadcastService: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.locator
    01-25 15:52:11.440 1781-2447/? D/k: Processing package: com.locator
    01-25 15:52:11.440 1781-1781/? D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.vision from APK com.google.android.gms
    01-25 15:52:11.460 1781-2447/? D/GassUtils: Found app info for package com.locator:1. Hash: 607a580ba8b114d1bb81233a4f43c87943595c82273a2c0687ee3129357d1d28
    01-25 15:52:11.460 1781-2447/? D/k: Found info for package com.locator in db.
    01-25 15:52:11.480 1600-1600/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
    01-25 15:52:11.480 1600-1600/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
    01-25 15:52:11.640 2408-2408/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    01-25 15:52:12.230 2473-2473/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
    01-25 15:52:12.260 1781-1823/? I/Icing: Indexing 15DBDA826A510ED8E77488BBA6CDEF77984857D4 from com.google.android.gms
    01-25 15:52:12.280 2473-2473/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    01-25 15:52:12.280 2473-2473/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
    01-25 15:52:12.300 2473-2473/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
    01-25 15:52:12.310 1301-1314/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.locator/.MainActivity} from uid 0 on display 0
    01-25 15:52:12.320 2473-2473/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    01-25 15:52:12.320 2482-2482/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
    01-25 15:52:12.760 1781-1823/? I/Icing: Indexing 15DBDA826A510ED8E77488BBA6CDEF77984857D4 from com.google.android.gms
    01-25 15:52:12.760 1781-1823/? E/Icing: Not enough disk space for indexing
    01-25 15:52:12.760 1781-1823/? I/Icing: Cannot sync untrimmable corpus: no sync
    01-25 15:52:12.760 1781-1823/? I/Icing: Indexing done 15DBDA826A510ED8E77488BBA6CDEF77984857D4
    01-25 15:52:12.760 1781-1823/? E/Icing: Aborting indexing of corpus apps
    01-25 15:52:12.850 2482-2482/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
    01-25 15:52:12.970 2482-2497/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    01-25 15:52:13.000 2482-2497/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
    01-25 15:52:13.020 2482-2497/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    01-25 15:52:13.020 2482-2497/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f5ada586280, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    01-25 15:52:13.430 1301-1324/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed 
    01-25 15:52:15.600 1301-2437/? W/DropBoxManagerService: Dropping: system_app_strictmode (10 > 0 bytes)
    01-25 15:52:17.320 1301-1585/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 1557:com.android.printspooler/u0a42 (adj 15): empty #17
    01-25 15:52:17.330 1301-1315/? W/libprocessgroup: failed to open /acct/uid_10042/pid_1557/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
    01-25 15:52:21.560 1301-1334/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
    01-25 15:52:21.610 1301-1301/? D/BackupManagerService: Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED dat=package:com.google.android.gms flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
    01-25 15:52:21.610 1301-1301/? I/BackupManagerService: Unbinding ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportService}
    01-25 15:52:21.620 1600-1600/? I/GCoreNlp: shouldConfirmNlp, NLP off. Ensuring opt-in disabled
    01-25 15:52:21.630 1540-1540/? I/Launcher: Deferring update until onResume
    01-25 15:52:21.670 1301-1301/? V/BackupManagerService: Connected to transport ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportService}
    01-25 15:52:21.680 1301-1301/? V/BackupManagerService: Registering transport com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService::com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService = com.android.internal.backup.IBackupTransport$Stub$Proxy@8c7a28f
    01-25 15:52:21.700 1600-1600/? W/GmsBackupAccountManager: Backup account not found in gmscore.
    01-25 15:52:21.720 1781-2500/? D/PackageBroadcastService: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=com.google.android.gms
    01-25 15:52:21.750 1600-2501/? W/GmsBackupAccountManager: Backup account not found in gmscore.
    01-25 15:52:21.770 1600-2501/? I/Backup: [BackupTransportMigratorService] Component name not found : com.google.android.backuptransport/com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService
    01-25 15:52:21.780 1600-2501/? I/Backup: [BackupTransportMigratorService] Component name not found : com.google.android.backup/com.google.android.backup.BackupTransportService
    01-25 15:52:21.780 1600-2501/? I/Backup: [BackupTransportMigratorService] Successfully migrated to use GMS     BackupTransportService!
    01-25 15:52:22.850 1781-1823/? I/Icing: Indexing 15DBDA826A510ED8E77488BBA6CDEF77984857D4 from com.google.android.gms
    01-25 15:58:37.660 1301-1318/? I/UsageStatsService: User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Don't use this class.  GPSTracker is completely broken in a dozen ways.  See http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/ for an explanation of why.